# Integral difference is non-negative

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

**Problem**
This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396957/sufficient-condition-for-function-to-be-monotonic-increasing).

Let $G$ be a proper prior distribution for $\theta\in[0,1]$ and $a\in(0,1)$ be a fixed value. I'd like to show that the following quantity is non-negative for any $a$ and for any integer $0\leq x\leq n-1$,
$$
g(x)=\int_{a}^1 s^{x+1}(1-s)^{n-x-1}dG(s)\int_{0}^{a} t^{x}(1-t)^{n-x}dG(t)-\int_{a}^1 s^{x}(1-s)^{n-x}dG(s)\int_{0}^{a} t^{x+1}(1-t)^{n-x-1}dG(t)
$$

---

I've simulated that this is true when $G$ is uniform or some beta distributions. However, I have some trouble showing this algebraically. I can lower-bound the first product of integrals using Cauchy-Schwarz and upper-bound terms in the second product of integrals by the product of expectations over $G$, noting that $s$ and $1-s$ are negatively correlated. However, none of these give me useful results for showing $g(x)\geq 0$.

---

**Here's what I have so far:**

First let $f(s)=\frac{s}{1-s}$ and $h(s)=s^x (1-s)^{n-x}$. Then by expressing $\int_a^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)=\int_0^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)-\int_a^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)$ (and similarly for $\int_a^1 h(s) dG(s))$, we can rewrite
$$
g(x)=\int_{0}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)\int_{0}^{1} h(s)1(s\leq a)dG(s)-\int_0^1 h(s) dG(s)\int_0^1 f(s)h(s)1(s\leq a)dG(s)
$$
Now the first product can be bounded below by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
\int_{0}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)\int_{0}^{1} h(s)1(s\leq a)dG(s)\geq \int_0^1 f(s)^{1/2}h(s)1(s\leq a) dG(s)=\int_0^a f(s)^{1/2}h(s) dG(s)
$$
The second product can be bounded above by noting that on $(0,1)$, $h(s)$ attains the maximum at $s=x/n$ and $f(s)$ is increasing on $(0,a)$.
$$
\int_0^1 h(s) dG(s)\int_0^1 f(s)h(s)1(s\leq a)dG(s)\leq f(a)h\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\int_0^a h(s) dG(s)
$$
Putting everything together, I get
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)&\geq& \int_0^a f(s)^{1/2}h(s) dG(s)-f(a)h\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\int_0^a h(s) dG(s)\\
&=&\int_0^a \left[f(s)^{1/2}-f(a)h\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\right] h(s) dG(s)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now on $s\in(0,a)$, $f(s)^{1/2}-f(a)h\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ may not always be greater than 0, but I need to show that the integral is (if possible) - it may also be the case that my bounds are not tight enough.

---

**Another thought:**

Since
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)&=&\int_{0}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)\int_{0}^{a} h(s)dG(s)-\int_0^1 h(s) dG(s)\int_0^a f(s)h(s)dG(s)\\
&=&\int_0^a\left(\int_{0}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)- f(t)\int_0^1 h(s) dG(s)\right)h(t)dG(t)
\end{eqnarray*}
then I just need to show that for $t\in(0,a)$, 
$$
\int_{0}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)- f(t)\int_0^1 h(s) dG(s)\geq 0
$$
or after substitution 
$$
\frac{t}{1-t}\leq \frac{\int_{0}^1 \left(\frac{s}{1-s}\right)s^x(1-s)^{n-x}dG(s)}{\int_0^1 s^x(1-s)^{n-x} dG(s)}\hspace{3mm}\forall t\in(0,a)
$$
The LHS is just a particular value of $f(t)=\frac{t}{1-t}$ on a constrained range $(0,a)$, while the RHS seems to be a weighted average of $f(t)$ over a larger range (i.e. $(0,1)$). Does this inequality always hold? Does it depend on the prior $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be easier than initially thought:

\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)&=&\int_{a}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)\int_{0}^{a} h(t)dG(t)-\int_a^1 h(s) dG(s)\int_0^a f(t)h(t)dG(t)\\
&=&\int_0^a\left(\int_{a}^1 f(s)h(s)dG(s)- f(t)\int_a^1 h(s) dG(s)\right)h(t)dG(t)\\
&=&\int_0^a\left(\int_{a}^1 [f(s)-f(t)]h(s)dG(s)\right)h(t)dG(t)
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $f(\cdot)$ is continuous and increasing on $(0,1)$, $f(s)\geq f(t)$ since $s\in(a,1)$ and $t\in(0,a)$. Therefore, $g(x)\geq 0$ as desired.